# KeyContainer (RSA)

Tags: c#, rsacryptoserviceprovider

Can anyone (e.g. a hacker) get the `KeyContainerInfo` of my programm or is it stored which programm got which KeyContainer? I've tried to create a new project where I tried to decrypt a file, which was encrypted with RSA from another programm, with the same `KeyContainerInfo` - it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes KeyContainerInfo can be getting with debugger or disassemble exe/dll.

RSA working with key-pair value system. You need to use private key for encryption and you need public key for decryption.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.              * i know how rsa works :p have you any answers how i can prevent this?✌

Comment: You can try it with Cryptool 2 with easly, then make your own development. Are you sure it was encrypted with RSA? May be developer use 3DES? May be developer add static values to private key before encryption.

Comment: Yeah, it was encrypted with RSA. Thx ✌

Comment: You need private key for decryption. Private key has attributes more than public key. You can check below url for C# <-> Java for signature:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6623/Porting-Java-Public-Key-Hash-to-C-NET
Note: signature preparing with private key and validating with public key, encryption preparing with public key and decryption with private key.